# Are different parts of the human body considered more/less auspicious?

Tags: body

I can understand squeamishness about organs of excretion - but are feet less auspicious?  Didn't Krishna wash Sudama's feet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes as per the scriptures. The part of the body which is above the navel is considered as pure but not so the part that lies below.

> Manu Smriti 1.92. **Man is stated to be purer above the navel** (than
>   below); hence the Self-existent (Svayambhu) has declared the purest
>   (part) of him (to be) his mouth.

Similarly, from the Dharma Sutras of Baudhayana (BDS):

> After tying or untying the lower garment, he should wash himself or
>   else touch wet grass, cowdung, or the earth. When he is engaged in
>   ritual activity, he should avoid touching below the navel, **for a
>   vedic text states: ‘A man’s body is clean above the navel and unclean
>   below the navel’**
>
> **BDS 1.10.20**

And the Vedic text it is referring to is the Taitiriya Samhita 6.1.3.4 (Krishna Yajur Veda).

Comment: Since Vaishyas came from Purusha's thighs they are as "impure" as so-called "sudras".  So why can one read the vedas and not the other? @rickross

Comment: I don't know why.. but it is so stated in the scriptures..@SK

Comment: @SK , these distinctions are for humans, not bhagavan. if his feet are impure, scriptures wouldnt say 'fall at his lotus feet'